# Crash issue on CFAbsoluteTime()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crashlytics

I am getting a few crashes on the last line of this code snippet :

```
let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let timePassedInSeconds = currentTime - Defaults[.absoluteStartGameTime]!
let time = worldTime.realGameSecondsToGameTime(Int(timePassedInSeconds))  // hours, days
```

It looks like the execution does not even enter the realGameSecondsToGameTime method, since crashlytics shows this very line as the crash line. The only thing that would make sense to me is a Double to Int conversion fail or timePassedInSeconds being nil.

However, Defaults[.absoluteStartGameTime] is a CFAbsoluteTime() value which is explicitly set when the game is first initiated with the line :

```
Defaults[.absoluteStartGameTime] = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
```

The exception message is :

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe
    SKSceneUtils.calculatePlayerMoney(SKLabelNode) -> () (SKSceneUtils.swift:129)
```

and it is never changed again anywhere in the code. Any ideas what could be causing this ?

Comment: What is the crash/exception message?  It seems likely that your force unwrap is the issue. Even though you say that value shouldn't be nil, can you use a conditional unwrap to try and handle the condition

Comment: The dreaded EXC_BREAKPOINT. Editing message to add this above too.

Comment: It seems `Defaults` means `NSUserDefaults`. What did you do with subscript of `Defaults`?

Comment: See my edited comment. It seems that your value is likely nil despite your initialisation. Can you use a conditional unwrap?

Comment: I am actually using https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults for all my settings storage.

Comment: Thanks Paulw, I can definitely have a conditional unwrap, but the issue is that if the value is nil, nothing will work in the game. This time setting is pretty much a required initialization. Thinking about it a bit more, I am wondering whether I have added this piece of code after some players have  already starting playing the game and forgot about it. I will look into my versioning control to check this. Not sure if there is a way for crashlytics to show when the app was installed on the target device(probably not i would think). But it's definitely a possibility.

Comment: Can't crashalytics provide the version/build number?  Is the value supposed to be set the first time the user *ever* runs the game?  If so, perhaps you could use the date from the app receipt to set a reasonable value if it is nil?

Comment: Exactly yes. It is set when the user initiates the game and then never changed unless they reset. The build is actually the latest one[but i only now setup crashlytics, so could be happening earlier] and it is actually 3 users that have initiated 10 crashes at the moment. The game has been up for about 2 months, but i guess there may be a handful of people that were hurt by this and still trying. I can probably add a reasonable default indeed. Weird bug this one :/